# Filter option to bring back ALL results

Tags: javascript, jquery, filter

Good morning

I am trying to implement a filter function. I have multiple fields to filter, but the one that is causing me a real headache is a radio button field for included baggage.

Before I only had the options true or false. But as it makes no sense I am in need for a third option (here called "any"), if the user does not care about Baggage.

If he selects ANY as his option of choice I will get back all of the results, either their value is true or false.
How can this be solved?

```
<div id="filter__BaggageIncluded">
    <div class="custom-controls-stacked">
        <div class="custom-control custom-radio">
             <input id="select__BaggageIncluded_any" name="select__BaggageIncluded" type="radio" value="any" class="custom-control-input" checked />
             <label class="custom-control-label" for="select__BaggageIncluded_any">any</label>
        </div>
        <div class="custom-control custom-radio">
             <input id="select__BaggageIncluded_true" name="select__BaggageIncluded" type="radio" value="true" class="custom-control-input" />
             <label class="custom-control-label" for="select__BaggageIncluded_true">yes</label>
        </div>
        <div class="custom-control custom-radio">
             <input id="select__BaggageIncluded_false" name="select__BaggageIncluded" type="radio" value="false" class="custom-control-input" />
             <label class="custom-control-label" for="select__BaggageIncluded_false">no</label>
       </div>
   </div>
</div>



function SetFilter() {    
     return $("#select__BaggageIncluded_" + $(this).data("baggage")).is(":checked");
}


/*The divs to be filtered look like this:*/
<div data-baggageincluded="true">...</div>
or
<div data-baggageincluded="false">...</div>
```

Comment: What should be return if ANY?

Comment: When it's `any`, don't add that part to the filter.  (which is the only relevant part and the only part you've not included in your code...)

Comment: `if (filter != "any") { var options = $(".options").filter("[data-baggeincluded=" + filter + "]"); }`

Comment: @Martin: if ANY it should return true AND false results

Comment: @freedomn-m I have to include this filter anyhow, because it could be the case that the user had baggage included = false selected before. Then I have to change that setting

Comment: Without knowing how you build/use the filter, it's only 2nd guessing.  If you're using `$("[data-baggageincluded=" + filter + "]")` or `$(..).filter` then it's trivial, but if you're doing something else, we need to know what that something else is to help you otherwise you just respond with "no that won't work" without any further information.

Comment: In summary, in your SetFilter() function you currently return `.is(":checked")` which gives you a bool.  I don't fully understand that because what's `this`?    You need to change that to get the selected filter from the radio: `$("[name=select__BaggageIncluded]").val()` then handle `true`/`false`/`any` correctly, not just a bool.

Comment: I run through all results and check if the id of the current result (this) is equal to the selected value. If this is the case, I'll display it, The problem is now, that my results only have the value true or false in this case. If I select radiobutton ANY it should display true AND false values. 
As I have more filters in my list I cannot only ignore that specific part of the filter.
Maybe it's an option to have a second (duplicate) function. One with that baggage filter included (in case the selected value is true or false) and one without that filter (in case the selected filter is ANY).